# can ckeditor update database content?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ckeditor

can you give me a way to save the contents of the ckeditor to the database?

i have 0% idea on how to make things work for this would be the first time to be use one. i've searched on google but it always shows the fckeditor(are they the same?). also, i've tried some codes with AJAX on it but still couldn't make it work because it requires some plugin and i don't actually understand it.

anyway, i'am using the 4.0 version of ckeditor and would prefer php or javascript code because i don't really know AJAX. here's my trial code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
-->

<?php
include('global.php');
?>

<html>
<head>

    <script>
        var type = 'Admin';

        <!-- editableContent -->
        window.onload = function (){
            if(type=='Admin'){
            document.getElementById('opener').contentEditable= true;
            document.getElementById('main').contentEditable= true;
            // We need to turn off the automatic editor creation first.
            CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
            var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'opener' );
            var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'main' );
            }
            else{
            document.getElementById('opener').contentEditable= false;
            document.getElementById('main').contentEditable= false;
            }
        }

        function showHTML () {
        document.getElementById('textpad').textContent = textEditor.document.body.innerHTML;
        return;
        }

    </script>


    <title>Inline Editing by Code &mdash; CKEditor Sample</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <link href="ckeditor/samples/sample.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

        #editable
        {
            padding: 10px;
            float: left;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="opener">
    <?
    $result= mysql_query ("SELECT * from text_tb WHERE categoryName='index'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row[1];
        }
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
    <?
    $result= mysql_query ("SELECT * from text_tb WHERE categoryName='about'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row[1];
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be 100% on target but it is what I've used and it works well.  TinyMCE uses the HTML **textarea** tag and some JavaScript to allow the client to format the information.  Then an ordinary "submit" sends the content of the textarea to the server, where you receive it in a POST-method request and you can store it in the data base.

Sample JS for TinyMCE:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,bullist,numlist,|,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,|,removeformat,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,formatselect,charmap,emotions,iespell,",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true
});

</script>
```

Link here: http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: i haven't tried your codes, but i don't think it will work. not on being pessimistic, but we are using two different editors which most probably use different attributes or something. plus, i don't have that .js thingy that i think deals with the saving, and lastly, those appears to be more like a properties section. yet, thank you very much for sharing this to me. thumbs up!

Comment: hi there. since i'm loosing all hope on ckeditor, i tried tinymce and i finished it in one sitting. thanks a lot! thumbs up!

Comment: Great!  Glad it was helpful for you, ~Ray

Answer (score 0):

The ckeditor documentation offers a very simple and easy way:

```
<form method="post">
    <p>
        My Editor:<br>
        <textarea name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
```

@ http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed-section-4

On the server side then you only have to

```
mysql_query("insert into yourtable (yourtextfield) VALUES ( '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editor1'])."')");
```

though I strongly suggest you to use prepared statements as offered by the PHP PDO Extensions. Prepared statements are much more secure.

Comment: i tried your code but it does not save the editor content on the DB. when it refreshes on the button click, it still shows the same query result.

Comment: my mistake about this comment^ it appears that there is an error and it says undefined index `opener` as you can see, i don't have any textarea on my code because i'am using an inline ckeditor, for that i placed the div id `opener` and there goes the bug. i hope you can give other option. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> [...] would prefer php or javascript code because i don't really know AJAX.

In fact, AJAX is a mix of PHP and JavaScript :P You can't update database content without a server side language(PHP), but using a client side language (JavaScript) you can "talk" to a server side script, that's what we call AJAX..

Anyway, as Ray Paseur said, usually you post a form containing textarea with the value of edited content but in your case you seems to be using the new Inline editing feature of the 4.0 version ?

So in this case, to access the value of the edited content you'll have to get the content of the div you've edited like this :

```
var opener_content=document.getElementById("opener").innerHTML;
var main_content=document.getElementById("main").innerHTML;
```

This will gives you the HTML code generated by the editor. Just do this in a function you call from maybe a "save changes" button in your page, then send those variables to your server with AJAX... (I would really suggest you to learn more about AJAX, it's more simple than it seams.)

But, if you don't want to learn AJAX right now, you can add an hidden form on your page with empty textareas, when the save button is clicked you fill these textarea with the 2 variables above, then you post this form via JavaScript and save data in PHP using the `$_POST` variable ! Its gonna work, even if it's an ugly and lazy solution :)

Comment: if ever i'll try your answer, i would go for the second option.(laughs) but, i'll place that last, i would still try and search for better solution. thanks a lot!